# Game Library with Support for RPython

Tags: python, game-engine, pypy, rpython

Are there any Python game libraries (Pygame, Pyglet, etc.) with support for RPython? Or game libraries specifically made for RPython? Or bindings for a game library for RPython?

Comment: Why? I don't think it's worth the effort, given that RPython is (1) an rather unpleasant language to program in, and (2) not intended for anything but writing virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check out the gameboy interpreter written in RPython, pygirl. https://bitbucket.org/pypy/lang-gameboy

Answer (score 0):

RPython is not Python. They are *different* languages even though it just so happens that you can execute RPython code with a Python interpreter and get similar effects (much more slowly) to running the compiled RPython program. It is **extremely** unlikely for there to ever be any reasonable Python library (game library or any other kind) that also works in RPython. It would have to be specifically written for RPython, and if it worked in RPython it would be so inflexible when considered as a regular Python library that nobody would use it in that context.

If you want to program in a lower level compiled language with game libraries, use C# or Java. RPython is not a good competitor (in large part because it has very few libraries for anything, not even much of a standard library).

If you want to program in Python, use Python (possibly use the PyPy implementation of Python, which can be faster than the standard Python interpreter if it supports all the libraries you're using). RPython will not help you write Python code that goes faster.

If your goal is not to specifically produce a game, but rather to do some project in RPython because you want to learn RPython specifically, then that's a perfectly reasonable aim. But writing a game in will probably not be the most helpful project for learning to write RPython; you should probably consider writing some sort of interpreter instead, since that's what RPython is designed to do.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Yep, but RPython doesn't bring much to the table if all you're using it for is to call C. You can call C libraries from Java or C# too, and get a similar static OO model with much more support and other libraries available. It makes sense to write things in RPython that are sufficiently "interpreter-like" to benefit from its killer features (e.g. automatic addition of GC and JIT compilation to the "interpreted language"). If you're not benefiting from those then RPython doesn't do much for you.

Comment: I don't know, but I've written non-interpreter-related stuff in RPython. It isn't really that bad, outside of getting used to the error messages. I even wrote a directory tree walker in it...and then added a JIT for sheer fun(??). I mean, it takes getting used to, but it isn't really that bad.